# Not able to get the locate the element by using xpath or css selector

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

```
<div class="et_pb_button_module_wrapper et_pb_button_4_tb_header_wrapper et_pb_button_alignment_center et_pb_button_alignment_phone_center et_pb_module "> 
   <a class="et_pb_button et_pb_button_4_tb_header full-width-btn et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light" href="https://pegramonline.com/compare-insurance-companies-charlotte-nc/">Get a Quote</a>
</div>
```

I tried to locate `<a>` element and still it could not locate it..any other suggestion please...the class name has a space

By.cssSelector(“a[class=’et_pb_button et_pb_button_4_tb_header full-width-btn et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light’]”);

By.cssSelector(“a.et_pb_button.et_pb_button_4_tb_header.full-width-btn.et_hover_enabled.et_pb_bg_layout_light”);

By.xpath(“//a[contains(@class, ‘et_pb_button’) and contains(@class, ‘et_pb_button_4_tb_header') and contains(@class, ‘full-width-btn')
and contains(@class, ‘et_hover_enabled’) and  contains(@class, ‘et_pb_bg_layout_light’)]”);

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine if you try to put a property color or anything else in this **CODE**

```
a.et_pb_button.et_pb_button_4_tb_header.full-width-btn.et_hover_enabled.et_pb_bg_layout_light{
    color:red;
}
```

Or

```
a[class=’et_pb_button et_pb_button_4_tb_header full-width-btn et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light’]{
    color:red;
}
```

then you can easily understand that it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways to click in Selenium.

Use the below xpath

```
//a[contains(text(),'Get a Quote')]
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Get a Quote')]")).click();
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Get a Quote')]"))).click();
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Get a Quote')]"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Get a Quote')]"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(button).click().build().perform();
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Comment: I verified and it has only 1 element. Why i dont want to use driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Get a Quote')]")) is i have multiple links on the same page which has this same text and i want to test all the links individually.